# Line density plot for many times series with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kernel-density, density-plot

edit: alpha = 0.1 is the top plot. I tried lower alpha values too. There are about 20k lines in the dark navy zone. I want to visualize where they are most dense but as a line plot rather than box or violin.

I have a data where I have hourly speed profiles for multiple streets. When I plot it the lines they overlap and it is very hard to tell where the frequency is high. The plot I have with the raw data looks like below.

[image]

I want to show it as a 2D density plot or anything that looks meaningful.

I will try to visualize what I tried with some fake data below and appreciate any suggestions to improve the below plots if I am doing something wrong. I am unsure about my KDE implementations.

```
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    np.random.seed(1)
    X = np.tile(np.linspace(0,24,96),reps=100)
    elements = np.array([-0.56339789, -0.37344139, -0.18348489,  0.00647161,  0.19642811,
            0.38638461,  0.5763411 ,  0.7662976 ,  0.9562541 ,  1.1462106 ,
            1.3361671 ,  1.5261236 ,  1.7160801 ,  1.9060366 ,  2.0959931 ,
            2.28594959,  2.47590609,  2.66586259,  2.85581909,  3.04577559])
    probability = np.array([7.35833333e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.33437500e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
           3.59375000e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 3.43750000e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
           3.23958333e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.10416667e-02,
           0.00000000e+00, 5.62500000e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 9.37500000e-04,
           0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 4.16666667e-04])
   
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
for s in range(0,100):
    ax.plot(arr.T[0][:96],arr.T[1][s*96:(s+1)*96],color='navy')
    ax.margins(0)
```

[image]

```
Y = np.random.choice(elements, 96 * 100, p = probability)
arr = np.vstack([ X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
data = {"hour":arr.T[0], "FE":arr.T[1]}
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=data, x="hour", y="FE", fill=True, levels=10,shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
ax.set_xlim(0,24)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5,3)
```

[image]

I also tried KDE estimation:

```
 from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

   def construct_grids(batch):
    """Construct the map grid from the batch object

    Parameters
    ----------
    batch : Batch object
        The object returned by :func:`fetch_species_distributions`

    Returns
    -------
    (xgrid, ygrid) : 1-D arrays
        The grid corresponding to the values in batch.coverages
    """
    # x,y coordinates for corner cells
    xmin = 0 
    xmax = 24
    ymin = np.min(arr[1,:])
    ymax = np.max(arr[1,:])

    # x coordinates of the grid cells
    xgrid = np.arange(xmin, xmax, 1)
    # y coordinates of the grid cells
    ygrid = np.arange(ymin, ymax, 0.1)

    return (xgrid, ygrid[:-1])

X, Y = construct_grids(arr)
X, Y  = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
xy = np.vstack([ X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T



kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.1).fit(arr)
Z = kde.score_samples(xy)
Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)
levels = np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 15)
ax = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=levels, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you just draw your lineplot, but with a low alpha (e.g.`alpha=0.1`)?

Comment: I don't think you want a 2D KDE here ... maybe you want a 1D KDE at each x value that you then stack into an array as columns and represent in a `plt.pcolormesh`? But I would try @JohanC's suggestion first.

Comment: The top plot is with alpha = 0.1 and it still overlaps a lot. I can try the pcolormesh suggestion. Thanks! I will update how that looks like

Comment: Maybe a fan chart could be implemented in this case, as shown in these questions: [Making a Python Fan Chart / Fan Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807169/making-a-python-fan-chart-fan-plot), [Creating a fanchart from a series of Monte Carlo projections in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146705/creating-a-fanchart-from-a-series-of-monte-carlo-projections-in-python)